# jQuery set ISO charset to ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

i'm using jQuery for sending ajax requests to the server, but i have some problems with the charset. In the [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function documentation is written that data is always sent in UTF-8 according to the W3C XMLHTTPRequest standard, so i don't think that jQuery allows you to change the request charset (except if you load a script, but that's not my case).

So do you know a way to set the ISO-8859-1 charset for the ajax request in jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is not possible. You might want to try to override the `Content-Type` Request header within your `ajax` call. I tried this with:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/exec/seoportservice.pl',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {
     foo: "bar"
  },
  dataType: 'text',
  beforeSend: function(xhr){
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'test');
  },
  success: function(data){
    console.log('success: ' + data);
  },
});
```

This actually will override the `Content-Type` header, but still `charset=UTF-8` is set.

So I guess you will have to handle the Encoding serverside.